# "Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax" - Insert statement not working in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb, sql-insert

```
<?php
    include 'db_connection.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $conn = OpenCon();
    echo "<br><br>Connected Successfully";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'customer'('customer name','password','email','phone number') VALUES([$name], [$password], [$email], [$phone]);";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
?>
```

This code is giving me the error while trying to use INSERT statement. I created the DBConenction using $conn variable.

Comment: Remove the square brackets around parameters in the `VALUES` part.

Comment: Hi, in order to get help on an error you should also post the error message. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid unwanted semicolon at the end and remove the single quote from table name. Try with the following. Also since 2 of your fields contain space in between them you can avoid using single quote and use `` backticks .

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (`customer name`,password, email, `phone number`) VALUES ('$name','$password','$email', '$phone') ";
```

Comment: Glad to help :) . You can accept this answer if you find it useful.

Comment: This opens the code to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for your code

I assume that your `name`, `password`, `email` and `phone` are strings.

So they must appear between quotes in your final requests, so

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'customer'('customer name','password','email','phone number') VALUES([$name], [$password], [$email], [$phone]);";
```

Change to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'customer'('customer name','password','email','phone number') VALUES('[$name]', '[$password]', '[$email]', '[$phone]')";
```

In addition, and to avoid SQL injection, you should escape the string you get from the POST request, so you should replace

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

by

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
```

And moved after the creation of your connexion.

## Better solution (if you can)

The best solution to handle databases in PHP is using prepared request, or even better: Using an ORM like [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html). It will be far more secure and reliable.

Comment: Have you verified the name of the columns in your SQL statement ? Names with spaces seems quite crazy

Comment: Or can you output the generated SQL (with random values to avoid disclosing password) ?

Comment: Escaping with `mysqli_real_escape_string` will do very little, if not next to nothing to prevent [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.